# How to configure protractor with cucumber framework in intelliJ Idea to run the automation testscripts

Tags: selenium, intellij-idea, protractor, cucumber

How to configure protractor with cucumber framework in intelliJ Idea to run the automation test scripts.

Right Now I am running my scripts in Command prompt and using Notepad++ as editor.

System configuration
Node.Js 
Java JDK 
Node_modules 
Protractor 
cucumber 
chai

Answer (score 0):

You need IntelliJ Ultimate Edition to run protractor and Node.js based tests. Community edition does not support Node.js plugin.

The detailed information on how to setup IntelliJ for Protractor can be found here: [Protractor Setup on IntelliJ - Software Automata](https://softwareautomata.wordpress.com/2017/07/09/protractor-setup-on-intellij/)